# Problem during Elastic beanstalk autoscaling

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I just started using elastic beanstalk.I am testing a golang web application the number of requests ranges from 10k to 450k per minute.During scaling i am getting "BackendConnectionErrors", "HTTPCode ELB 5XX", "HTTPCode Backend 5XX".
Is this normal? How do i avoid from request errors when scale up or down?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable access logs on the load balancer to see exactly what type of error is being generated, as the different 5xx errors can be caused by a variety of different things.

If your requests are long lived, it might be an issue where instances are getting terminated while there are still in flight requests (increase the connection draining/deregistration delay on the ELB)

If its happening when scaling out (adding instances) then the ELB healthcheck might be marking the instances healthy before they application is actually up, in which case you should change the healthcheck path to better represent your application

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-troubleshooting.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html